# Need to override previously written rewrite rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have some rewrite rules in an htaccess file. I'm still getting into it so theres a few things I'm unsure of.
Basically I want all pages (except the /register page) to be rewritten like this: http://www.example.com/about -> http://www.example.com?page=about

To get that right I wrote this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-_1-9]+)+/?$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I then wrote this rule below the one above thinking it would override it, but it doesnt...

```
RewriteRule ^register/?$ ./?page=login&option=register
```

So going to /register gives me a 404. However if I comment out the first rule then the register page works.
I was thinking it would work like CSS where writing a new rule below would take precedence. 
How would I get this right and how do you override previously written rewrite rules?

Thanks!

Comment: You have set `[L]` which makes the rule the last rule to execute if it matches. Any subsequent rules will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I took away the [L] and there's still the same problem

Comment: Since your second rule is more specific than your first one, you should swap them. `^register/?$` should be the first to be tested and you can add the `[L]` to that one, too.

Comment: You may want to fix regex while you are at it. Remove the nested quantifier and you can just as well use `\w` here, giving you: `^([\w-]+)/?$`

Comment: Thanks for the tip Qtax, I'll be using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess is not CSS -- especially when it comes to mod_rewrite instructions/rules.

The rules are executed from top to bottom. Therefore -- **put more specific rules at top and then more generic at bottom**.

In your case:

```
RewriteRule ^register/?$ ./?page=login&option=register [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-_1-9]+)+/?$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```